# Switching location frequently on VPN

Tags: privacy, vpn

Correct me in my assumptions/understandings in any of the following.

A common tool to reduce fingerprinting when on the internet is browser/user agent spoofing. Now, I've read you don't really want to be too random, or use browsers/versions that are too niche, because that may make you more unique and hence more identifiable.

In the same vein, does regularly/frequently switching locations on a VPN make you more identifiable?

For example, Can your identity be "triangulated" more easily if you watch topic X on youtube regularly, and your location varies from Country A, Country B, Country C, etc.?

Assume that cookies/cache are deleted between sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can your identity be "triangulated" more easily if you watch topic X on youtube regularly, and your location varies from Country A, Country B, Country C, etc.?

No. The chosen VPN exit is unrelated to the physical location of the user or its original IP address.

> In the same vein, does regularly/frequently switching locations on a VPN make you more identifiable?

There are lots of fingerprinting methods apart from cookies, cache or user agent. Regular changing the VPN exit might confuse some detection but it might also simply associate the fingerprint with "the user is using VPN". Or it simply ignores the users IP address in fingerprinting. Thus, it likely does not make any difference in tracking the user.